# Drawing a diagram in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-node

I am struggling to draw a `TikZ` picture. Here is what I want to draw (neglect the arrow that is crossed out). [image]

So far my graphics look like this:

[image]

And this is the code I have, so essentially I am struggling with horizontal arrows.

```
    \documentclass{standalone}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning}
    \usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,calligraphy}
    
    \tikzstyle{int}=[draw, fill=blue!20, minimum size=2em]
    \tikzstyle{init} = [pin edge={to-,thin,black}]
    
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
    
    \begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
    
                \node[rectangle,
                draw = black,
                minimum width = 2cm, 
                minimum height = 3cm, anchor = west] (t) at (0,0)  {DNN};   
                
                \node[rectangle,
                draw = black,
                minimum width = 3cm, 
                minimum height = 1cm, anchor = west, rotate = -90] (g) at (3.5,1.5)  {argmax};
            
                \node[rectangle,
                draw = black, left = of t,
                minimum width = 1cm, 
                minimum height = 0.4cm, yshift = 1.3cm, anchor = east] (u)  {Emb};  
            
                \node[rectangle,
                draw = black, left = of t,
                minimum width = 1cm, 
                minimum height = 0.4cm, yshift = 0.3cm, anchor = east] (v)  {Emb};  
                
                \node[rectangle,
                draw = black, left = of t,
                minimum width = 1cm, 
                minimum height = 0.4cm, yshift = 0.-1.3cm, anchor = east] (v)  {Emb};
                
                
                \node[rectangle,
                draw = black, left = of t,
                minimum width = 1cm, 
                minimum height = 0.4cm, yshift = -0.3cm, anchor = east] (v)  {Emb};
                
                \node(dots) at (-1.5,-0.7){\vdots};
                \node(dots) at (-1.5,0.9){\vdots};
                
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Please show what code you tried, so that people can see what work you've already done and start from there.

Comment: Thanks for your hint

Answer (score 5):

Not too different from what Miyase posted, but with different positioning tools and commands

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,calligraphy}

\tikzstyle{int}=[draw, fill=blue!20, minimum size=2em]
\tikzstyle{init} = [pin edge={to-,thin,black}]

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}

            \node[rectangle,
            draw = black,
            minimum width = 2cm, 
            minimum height = 3cm, anchor = west] (t) at (0,0)  {DNN};   
            
            \node[rectangle,
            draw = black,
            minimum width = 3cm, 
            minimum height = 1cm, anchor = west, rotate = -90] (g) at (3.5,1.5)  {argmax};
        
            \node[rectangle,
            draw = black, left = of t.north west, anchor=north east,
            minimum width = 1cm, 
            minimum height = 0.4cm] (emb1)  {Emb};  
        
            \node[rectangle,
            draw = black, below = 4mm of emb1,
            minimum width = 1cm, 
            minimum height = 0.4cm] (emb2)  {Emb};  
            
            \node[rectangle,
            draw = black, left = of t.south west, anchor=south east,
            minimum width = 1cm, 
            minimum height = 0.4cm, fill=blue!50] (emb4)  {Emb};

            \node[rectangle,
            draw = black, above = 4mm of emb4,
            minimum width = 1cm, 
            minimum height = 0.4cm, fill=blue!50] (emb3)  {Emb};
                        
            \path (emb1)--node[pos=0.25] {\vdots} (emb2);
            \path (emb3)--node[pos=0.25] {\vdots} (emb4);
            \foreach \i in {1,2,3,4}{
                \draw[->] (emb\i)--(emb\i-|t.west);
                \draw[->] (emb\i-|t.east)-- node[above]{Q\i}(emb\i-|g.south);
                \draw[<-] (emb\i.west)--++(180:5mm) node[left]{SNR};
            }
            \draw[->] (g)--++(0:1cm);
                
            
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I see you used a `foreach` loop. Since the original poster seems to be new to TikZ, I encourage them to have a look at it. Those loops are precious when doing complex figures!

Comment: @Miyase Not only the `foreach` but also another way of positioning `emb` nodes. They are adjusted to `DNN` margins. I would also use a `fit` node for `argmax` or other ways to adjust its height to be equal to `DNN`

Answer (score 4):

Here's a rudimentary answer. I hope you'll be able to twink to your taste.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning,calc}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,calligraphy}

\tikzstyle{int}=[draw, fill=blue!20, minimum size=2em]
\tikzstyle{init} = [pin edge={to-,thin,black}]

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}

            \node [rectangle,
            draw = black,
            minimum width = 2cm, 
            minimum height = 3cm, anchor = west] (t) at (0,0)  {DNN};
            
            \node[rectangle,
            draw = black,
            minimum width = 3cm, 
            minimum height = 1cm, anchor = west, rotate = -90] (g) at (4,1.5)  {argmax};
            \node (Q1) at (3.6,1.2)[left]{$Q_1$};
            \node (Q2) at (3.6,0.4)[left]{$Q_2$};
            \node (Q3) at (3.6,-0.4)[left]{$Q_3$};
            \node (Q4) at (3.6,-1.2)[left]{$Q_4$};
            \draw[->, >=latex] (Q1-|t.east)--(Q1.west);
            \draw[->, >=latex] (Q2-|t.east)--(Q2.west);
            \draw[->, >=latex] (Q3-|t.east)--(Q3.west);
            \draw[->, >=latex] (Q4-|t.east)--(Q4.west);
            \draw[->, >=latex] (g.north)--++(1,0);

            \node[rectangle,
            draw = black, left = of t,
            minimum width = 1cm, 
            minimum height = 0.4cm, yshift = 1.3cm, anchor = east] (u)  {Emb};  
            \draw[->, >=latex] (u.east)--(u-|t.west);
        
            \node[rectangle,
            draw = black, left = of t,
            minimum width = 1cm, 
            minimum height = 0.4cm, yshift = 0.3cm, anchor = east] (v)  {Emb};  
            \draw[->, >=latex] (v.east)--(v-|t.west);
            
            \node[rectangle,
            draw = black, left = of t,
            minimum width = 1cm, 
            minimum height = 0.4cm, yshift = 0.-1.3cm, anchor = east] (w)  {Emb};
            \draw[->, >=latex] (w.east)--(w-|t.west);            
            
            \node[rectangle,
            draw = black, left = of t,
            minimum width = 1cm, 
            minimum height = 0.4cm, yshift = -0.3cm, anchor = east] (x)  {Emb};
            \draw[->, >=latex] (x.east)--(x-|t.west);

            \draw[dotted] (u.south)--(v.north);
            \draw[dotted] (x.south)--(w.north);
           
            \draw[->, >=latex] ($(u.west)-(1,0)$) node[left]{SNR}--(u.west);
            \draw[->, >=latex] ($(v.west)-(1,0)$) node[left]{SNR}--(v.west);
            \draw[->, >=latex] ($(w.west)-(1,0)$) node[left]{SNR}--(w.west);
            \draw[->, >=latex] ($(x.west)-(1,0)$) node[left]{SNR}--(x.west);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: There is a small error on the left side of your image (lower dotted line). It should be `\draw[dotted] (w.north)--(x.south);`. You may also want to use some `yshift` so that the lines do not start right at the border.

Comment: Thanks, I corrected the typo.

Answer (score 2):

One more variant how you can draw this scheme. Used are `arrows.meta`, `fit` and `positioning` libraries, "Emb" nodes are positioned relative to each other, "DNN" and "argmax" use `fit` of coordinate  for top left and bottom right nodes corners. For nodes are defined two styles: `emb` and `FIT`:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                fit,
                positioning}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
            > = Straight Barb,
node distance = 4mm and 12mm,
   emb/.style = {draw, fill=#1, minimum width=10mm, minimum height=4mm,
                 node contents={Emb}},
   emb/.default = none,
   FIT/.style = {draw, fit=#1, inner sep=0pt},
                        ]
\node (n1)  [emb];
\node (n2)  [emb, below=of n1];
\node (n3)  [emb=blue!50, below=of n2];
\node (n4)  [emb=blue!50, below=of n3];
    \path   (n1)--node[pos=0.25] {\vdots} (n2)
            (n3)--node[pos=0.25] {\vdots} (n4);        
%
\coordinate[right=of n1.north east]     (dnn1);
\coordinate[right=of n4.south -| dnn1]  (dnn2);
\node (n5) [FIT=(dnn1) (dnn2), label=center:DNN] {};
%
\coordinate[right=of n5.north east]     (am1);
\coordinate[right=of n5.south -| am1]   (am2);
\node (n6) [FIT=(am1) (am2), label={[rotate=-90]center:argmax}] {};
%%
\foreach \i in {1,2,3,4}%
{
    \draw[->] (n\i) -- (n\i -| n5.west);
    \draw[->] (n\i -| n5.east)-- node[above] {Q\i} (n\i -| n6.west);
    \draw[<-] (n\i.west) --++ (-0.5,0) node[left] {SNR};
}
\draw[->] (n6) --++ (1,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]